# Install packages via yum without internet in centOS7

Tags: wget, yum, centos7

I guess there are 2 metods for the same 
method 1:CentOS DVD ISO YUM Repository

```
step 1:Download/Transfer CentOS DVD ISO
```

which is not working for me.

I used the command via

```
wget  http://mirror.lihnidos.org/CentOS/7/isos/x86_64/ CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso
```

but its downloading an html file not iso file

2nd method is custom yum repository

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because there is a space in your command ? Use this

```
wget http://mirror.lihnidos.org/CentOS/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso
```

Oh, and you can download the package you want in a .RPM format, and then use this command :

```
yum install MyPackage.rpm
```

Make sure to edit "MyPackage" by the name of your file :)

Answer (score 0):

For better resolving dependencies, you better to install via yum just like `yum localinstall MyPackage.rpm`